# PSEXEC redirect output to local file

Tags: vbscript, redirect, psexec

I need the correct way to accomplish this via a vbscript.

This works fine from command prompt:

```
psexec \\99.99.99.99 -u username -p password cmd.exe /c ver > output.txt
```

From the vbscript:

```
sTempFile = objFSO.GetTempName
sCmd = "psexec \\" & sIP & " -u " & sDomain & "\" & sUser & " -p " & sPassword & "    cmd /c ver  > " &  sTempFile 

WSHShell.Run sCmd, 1, True
```

I always get a runtime error: File not found

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: I just foundd out it is creating the file on the remote machine. I need it in the local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Dont know why but adding cmd /c also before psexec did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use the syntax below :
cmd /c ver  2>output.txt

and you are done!

If you want to append the output file

cmd /c ver  2>>output.txt